# Is it safe to allow POST access to the multi search API of ElasticSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

We are running an application using elasticsearch hosted on AWS. The client-side interface uses "ReactiveSearch" for vuejs, which makes POST requests against the "_msearch" interface described here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html

Reading the documentation I can't see anything that could make this approach unsafe e.g. removing data, but I wanted to make sure. The AWS documentation "recommends" to only leave "GET" open: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-ac.html

So is it safe to expose this endpoint to the public?

Here is the AWS-Policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:ESHttpPost",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-east-2:943306001616:domain/wimj/product/_msearch",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```